# How can I match an AWS account number to a key and secret

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

My client gave me a key and a secret to manage his EC2 things, but to make one of my AMI's available to run I have to fill in the Account Number. Is it possible to deduce the account number from the key and the secret?

Obviously I also asked the client for this information, but since it's weekend and I'm not fond of waiting I wanted to see if I could figure it out myself. Have you done this before?

Answer (score 2):

its not possible to get account number from key.

Comment: I feared as much :)